# overriding methods without subclassing in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I started on a new project recently and saw the usage of overriding like below for the first time.

```
public class SomeClass {
  public void myMethod() {
    XStream xstream = new XStream() {
            @Override
            protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
                return new MapperWrapper(next) {
 // the rest ommitted
```

Basically, it's overriding the wrapMapper() method of the XStream class in the thoughtworks xstream api but without having SomeClass to extend the XStream class.  I've worked with Java for a number of years but this is the first time I saw overriding being done like this.  Can someone explain the ins and out of it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

That's an [Anonymous Inner Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Answer (score 2):

In this case the XStream class is an anonymous inner class. Then you're overriding the method of your anonymous XStream class.

Answer (score 1):

The new implementation for

> wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next)

method is limited for this instance xstream

> XStream xstream

this type of overriding is creating a class that extends XStream, that's why it is called Anonymous, do not have a name and you can not have a reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

That is called an "Anonymous class". You can find a lot of documentation about this special syntax on Internet. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Search Google for Anonymous Inner Class in Java

That's pretty useful to implement interfaces or abstract Class methods on concrete objects

That's heavily used when working with threading (Runnable class)