# Java override method from another class without inheritance

Tags: java, overriding

I found a similar question here:
[overriding methods without subclassing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992668/overriding-methods-without-subclassing-in-java)

But mine a little different, I have two classes, 1 GUI based, and the other just methods to modify elements in first class. If it just editing the basic function, I meet no problem, but now I want to override a jbutton in first class method from the second class without inheriting it. Where do I have to start?

I have temporary solution which is that the second class extends JButton, override method I want to, and add that class to my GUI class (anonymous object or not, is doesn't matter). But I want to discover a way to find a way to my question, is it even possible? Thanks :)

**Edit**
Here's sample code:

First class, as it only a button in jframe, I only add these in constructor:
`ButtonOverrider bo=new ButtonOverrider();` -> this is the overrider class
`button=bo.overridePaintComponent(bo);` //first try
`button=bo.overridePaintComponent();` //second try
`bo.overridePaintComponent(bo);` //third try

And here's the ButtonOverrider method:

```
public JButton ButtonOverrider(JButton button) {
  button = new JButton() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
      Color.blue.brighter().brighter(), 0, getHeight(),
      getBackground().darker().darker());

      g2.setPaint(gp);
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      g2.dispose();

      super.paintComponent(g);
      super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
      super.setFocusPainted(false);
      super.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.yellow, 2));
      super.setText("Shuro");
    }
  };
  return button;
}
```

Comment: can you post minimal sample code showing what you want

Comment: `overriding` in its formal sense not possible without subclassing in my humble opinion

Comment: @RC. question updated

Comment: It seems to me like what you want to do is the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). A Decorator is a class which implements an interface and encapsulates an object of the same interface. Each method can be delegated to the encapsulated object, execute code before and/or after doing so or do something entirely different. Decorators have the nice ability to be stackable - you can wrap an object in a decorator in a decorator in a decorator.

Comment: You say your example is different to in the other question -  a GUI class, a class with methods, an anonymous class etc, are all classes - therefore they all follow the rules of what being a class is.

Answer (score 7):

> Where do I have to start?

With inheritance. That's the only way that overriding makes any sense. It's not clear *why* you don't want to use inheritance, but that really is the only way of overriding a method. Whether you use an anonymous class or a named one is irrelevant, but it *must* extend the class in order to override the method. That's simply the way overriding works in Java.

EDIT: The code you've shown in your updated question *does* use inheritance by creating an anonymous inner class... but it doesn't do what I expect you want it to, because it creates a *new* object rather than overriding the method on the *existing* object. Your parameter value is never used.

Comment: @A-SM: That *is* using inheritance. That's an anonymous inner class - you're extending `JButton`. But you're also completely ignoring the parameter - it's creating a *new* button.

Comment: :x I didn't have idea if that was inheritance, but if it is, then there should be a way to do what I write in my question right? That code doesn't change anything in my button.

Comment: @A-SM: No, there isn't be a way to do what you've asked, because you can't change the type of an existing object. As I said, you're completely ignoring the parameter, which is why that code doesn't work.